# What is the equivalent of ObjectFactory.Inject in StructureMap 3.0

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, structuremap, structuremap3

I recently upgraded to StructureMap 3.0 and noticed that ObjectFactory.Inject is missing. What is the equivalent for simple injection config that this method provided?

Comment: 3.0 moved a lot of methods to `ObjectFactory.Container`. Inject is there, but I'm now to structuremap. So I don't know if it's changed.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini I noticed that as well, but wanted to make sure that's the official response.

Comment: Official.. that will be difficult. The developer still hasn't released documentation for 3.0, and it might take sometime before docs happen as their making changes to support a new doc format. I've been using the master branch from git, and that's been a lot better since the source has comments that don't exist in any docs.

Comment: I have same question, and yay, I found it, it's in `ObjectFactory.Container`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned, 3.0 moved a lot of methods to `ObjectFactory.Container`. `Inject` is there, but `ObjectFactory` will be dropped out at 4.0. So avoid this approach.

`Inject` and a lot of methods are in the `Container` class. This is not a static class as `ObjectFactory` is. To deal with this you can configure like this:

```
var container = new Container(x =>
{
    x.For<IFooBar>().Use<FooBar>();
}

container.Inject(myObject);
```

OK, this works only if I'm in the same class, but sometimes you need `IContaner` class inside a controller and you create your `Container` at project Startup, in this case you can do this:

```
public MyController(ISession session, IContainer container)
{
    _session = session;
    _container = container;
}

public void DoSomeStuff()
{
    _container.Inject(new FooBar());
}
```

`IContainer` can be injected using your Dependency Resolver. In my case I'm using `System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver` with a custom `StructureMapDependencyResolver` so this `DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IContainer>().Inject(myService);` is possible too.